# how to use session with different label in loop in php

Tags: php, session

i have query in php.

```
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($qu)) { 
        $s=$res['start']; 
        $d=$res['end']; 
        $wr=$res['waypoint'];

$_SESSION['start' ]=$s;
$_SESSION['end' ]=$d;
$_SESSION['waypoint' ]=$wr; 
}

?>
```

In this session is overright and last value will store. i want each value from start to end of loop.

Comment: Then build an array and store the values... `$array['start'][] = $s`

Comment: so... use an array? `$_SESSION['start'][] = $s`?

Answer (score 2):

if you are looping and you want each value. Try the following:

```
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($qu)) { 
        $s=$res['start']; 
        $d=$res['end']; 
        $wr=$res['waypoint'];
        $_SESSION['start'][]=$s;
        $_SESSION['end'][]=$d;
        $_SESSION['waypoint'][]=$wr; 
}
```

This will create an array for each $_SESSION

You could simplify the loop to:

```
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($qu)) { 
        $_SESSION['start'][]=$res['start']; 
        $_SESSION['end'][]=$res['end'];
        $_SESSION['waypoint'][]=$res['waypoint']; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what i do is set a numeric value and increment it by 1 each loop.

```
 $a = 0;
 while($res=mysql_fetch_array($qu)) { 
    $s=$res['start']; 
    $d=$res['end']; 
    $wr=$res['waypoint'];

$_SESSION[$a]['start' ]=$s;
$_SESSION[$a]['end' ]=$d;   
$_SESSION[$a]['waypoint' ]=$wr; 
 $a++;
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: thanks , and if i want to retrive one value from session array then how can i?

Comment: i want to pass one value from array to java script function so how can i?

Comment: you would have to know what you are searching for and echo $_SESSION['4']['start'] or whatever. which would be the same as below.

Comment: echo $_SESSION[$a]['start']; is not working, can u help me, it retrive null. why?

Comment: if you aren't in a loop then php won't know what $a is equal to.  try using an actual key in the array.  echo $_SESSION[5]['start']  or some number you know exists as a key